# Characters comparison in a string then return an integer value and calculate the percentage

Tags: c#, string

I have 2 names that i have fetched from my database.

```
string query1 = SELECT FIRSTNAME FROM STUDENT;
string query2 = SELECT FIRSTNAME FROM CUSTOMER;
```

The result from query1 is say RESET and the result from query2 is for example SET. i want to compare the 2 strings and get the match as an integer and calculate the percentage. In the example above the match is 3. so the % will be 3/5 * 100. which C# function can i use to compare the strings? i want to do the comparison in C# code and not using SQL.

Comment: It isn't clear how should the match be done... Substring? Character by character? SR is a match of RESET? Give some examples.

Comment: As written in the linked other question, you need to give us the [String metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric)

Comment: Not certain, but looks like you're basically taking total - Levenshtein distance and then calculating the percentage?

Comment: @xanatos an matching character by character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will check if a string is a substring of another string (as given in your example RESET vs SET). Note that it's reflexive, so RESET vs SET == SET vs RESET. If you need to check for substrings (so RESE vs SET == 2/4 == 0.5 or something else) then you'll need to explain what you want.

```
public static double Percentage(string str1, string str2) {
    // Handling of empty strings. No divisions by zero here!
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str1) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(str2)) {
        return 0.0;
    }

    // str2 is contained in str1
    if (str1.Contains(str2)) {
        return 100.0 * str2.Length / str1.Length;
    }

    // str1 is contained in str2
    if (str2.Contains(str1)) {
        return 100.0 * str1.Length / str2.Length;
    }

    // No matching
    return 0.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given two strings, S of length n and R of length m, where n < m, you could do something like

```
float percentage = 0;
int index = R.substring(S);
if(index > 0) {
    percentage = R.Length / S.Length * 100;
}
```